# Yii app on Amazon EC2 how to make it work?

Tags: yii, amazon-ec2

I would like to deploy a `Yii` app to `Amazon EC2`.
I've installed `httpd`, `mysql`, `php` and all the necessary modules.
The app was running fine on my `wampserver` localhost.
I've transferred everything (DB, app folder) but I'm having issues with accessing the site. I see default apache site, and I see directory structure under **var/www/html/app** folder, and `var/www/html/app/web` gives a blank page (or Internal Server Error). I have a `.htaccess` file in `var/www/html/app/web`. I was searching a lot, and have found informations about `allowoverride`, virtual hosts (I have only IP, what is server name then? the IP?), etc, and have tried a few different things, but I don't want to mess it completely up, and I'm pretty sure it must be some very simple adjustments to make it work, but I don't know what (maybe some settings with EC2 like elastic IP? I dont yet have that one but I'm not sure I need it). I don't have much experience, can you please point me to the right direction what else I have to set in order to make it work? Thank you very much!

UPDATE: I have set Elastic IP up and registered a domain.

Comment: in the meanwhile I have applied a few commands I thought could help [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-deploy-app.html) (step 4), but now I just get: **Forbidden You don't have permission to access /app/web on this server.** (when I do it with Public DNS). When I try it with public IP, then I get this message: **Not Found The requested URL /app/web/ was not found on this server.** Which one should I use at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simply chosed another image, and without any special actions it works. The first was an Amazon Image, now it's an Ubuntu.